Looking for the title of a movie in the style of The NeverEnding Story
The main character was a boy who finds himself in another world, where a struggle for the kingdom is ongoing.
I remember that he is subjected to a series of tests, including a dilemma (to test the goodness in his heart): how would you react if you found money on the ground?

I'm pretty sure the movie is storybook. I own the french version on VHS and I remember the scene you are describing. 
Trailer
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hmQAoODg1ME
IMDB
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114556/  (it's weird that the cover makes it look animated while it isn't)
